# Url parameters to array/object

Tags: jquery, url

With jQuery.param i can do:

```
var myObject = {
  a: {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3
  },
  b: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
};
var recursiveEncoded = $.param( myObject );
var recursiveDecoded = decodeURIComponent( $.param( myObject ) );

recursiveDecoded; // "a[]=foo&a[]=bar&b[]=1&b[]=2&b[]=3"
```

But how to got:

```
var myObject = {
  a: {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3
  },
  b: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
};
```

from `"a[one]=1&a[two]=2&a[three]=3&b[]=1&b[]=2&b[]=3"` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value from URL Parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)

Comment: @Scimonster: Not a duplicate. They are after nested values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var myObject = {
  a: {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3
  },
  b: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
};

var json = JSON.stringify(myObject);
var _arr = decodeURIComponent($.param(JSON.parse(json)));
var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(_arr.split("=").join("&").split("&")));
var obj = [];
var tempObj = [];
var tempVals = [];    
$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
  if ( /\[/.test(value) ) {
    var props = value.split(/\[|\]/).slice(0, 2);
    tempObj.push(props);        
  };
    if ( !/\[/.test(value) ) {
    var vals = Number(value);
    tempVals.push(vals);
  };      
});    
$.when($.each(tempObj, function(index, value) {
   value.push(tempVals[index])
}))
.done(function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    obj.push(value.filter(Boolean))
  });
});    
console.log(obj);
```

Edit (update)

Utilizing a [forked version](https://github.com/dadario/jquery-bbq/blob/master/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js) (without `$.browser`, which returned `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined` at jsfiddle) of [jquery BBQ `$.deparam()` method](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) , try

```
    var myObject = {
      a: {
        one: 1,
        two: 2,
        three: 3
      },
      b: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    };

    var p = decodeURIComponent( $.param( myObject ));
    var d = $.deparam( p );
      console.log( p, d ); 
   // a[one]=1&a[two]=2&a[three]=3&b[]=1&b[]=2&b[]=3 
   // Object {a: Object, b: Array[3]}
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/6P7tf/